# My function is not returning anything in Delphi

Tags: function, delphi

Here is my code:

```
function encrypt(str: string): string;
  var
    j: integer;
    answer: string;
  begin
    answer := '';
    for j := 0 to system.Length(str) do
      begin
        if str[j] = ' ' then
          begin
            answer := answer + 'er ';
          end
        else
          begin
            answer := answer + str[j];
          end;
      end;
    answer := answer + 'er';
    result := answer;
  end;

procedure TForm1.btn_encryptClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    lbl_answer.Caption := encrypt(edt_main.Text);
  end;
```

I am getting no errors however the lbl_answer is not changing.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: I recommend that you activate `overflow checking` and `range checking` in `Project options - Delphi compiler - Compiling - Runtime errors`

Comment: Did you try observing the function's execution in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
for j := 0 to system.Length(str) do
```

It should read

```
for j := 1 to system.Length(str) do
```

In a string of length, *N*, the character indices are 1, 2, ..., *N*.

This is because strings in Delphi use 1-based indexing. In most other languages, the indices would have been 0, 1, 2, ..., *N* − 1.

But you also got the *number* of characters wrong: indeed, you try to enumerate *N* + 1 characters (0, 1, 2, ... *N*) in a string of length *N*. (Think about the case *N* = 3, for instance. 0, 1, 2, 3 are four -- not three -- indices!)

---

Buy why do you get a seemingly empty string out of the function? Well, that's because of [the internal layout of Delphi strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Long_String_Types). Before the first character (each character is two bytes), you have the length as a four-byte (32-bit) integer. `str[0]` will likely access the "character" before the first character. These two bytes are the MSBs of the length. Since your string likely has a length no greater than $FFFF, these are zero, so you get the null character. This will probably make the rendering of this string terminate at that point, making it look like the string is empty.

Comment: "*This is because strings in Delphi use 1-based indexing*" - unless you compile for iOS/Android in Delphi versions prior to 10.4, then [strings use 0-based indexing](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop#Use_0-Based_Strings) instead, unless you explicitly turn it off with [`{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi)). "*`str[0]` will likely access the "character" before the first character*" - accessing index 0 on a 1-based string will usually be silently remapped by the RTL to index 1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's why I said "likely". It seems to be the case here. I even tried it on my system, and it did give me the two MSBs of the length (even if I manually changed the two bytes to produce an ASCII `A`). Of course, there are no guarantees that this will always be the case. You shouldn't try to access `str[0]`.